# How Can I generate QR code and Show it on a PDF page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf-generation, qr-code

I am Building a Flutter App, and one of the Functionalities includes the following:

1- Generating Qr codes - no problem here if I am showing it on the screen.
2- Generating PDF file, then saving it and sharing it using native device Sharing, No problem here until I tried to include the Qr code in the PDF page!

I have been stuck with this for two days and tried too many approaches to solve this, sadly with no luck.

please help and thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Barcode widget from the pdf package. https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

```
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

//Barcode widget inside pdf.addPage()
pw.BarcodeWidget(
  color: PdfColor.fromHex("#000000"),
  barcode: pw.Barcode.qrCode(),
  data: "My data",
),
```

Comment: Hi! I used your above code to Print QR in my pdf but get following error: `Helvetica-Bold has no Unicode support see https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/wiki/Fonts-Management`  How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that it is an error and not a warning? I think this should help: https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/384

Comment: At last I made it. Thanks for your help. At a point after all was set, I wasn't getting the QR code displayed in pdf. Then I gave ```height: 70 ,width :70``` in Constructor of BarcodeWidget. And it also worked.

Answer (score 2):

using this package ([pdf package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf)) you can use like this -->

```
final pdf = pw.Document();    
pw.BarcodeWidget(
        data: "demo",
        barcode: pw.Barcode.qrCode(),
        width: 100,
        height: 50
    ),
```

***result is:*** 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have got the following answer from  DavBfr / dart_pdf  on GitHub and it worked:

Yes, there is a Widget for that:

BarcodeWidget(
            barcode: Barcode.qrCode(),
            data: 'here is a qrcode',
)

You can use the same widget for Flutter too: https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_widget

Comment: Hi, Can you share some code with me? I am going to implement the exact same thing. QR in PDF with some other info. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, can I add embedded image to this BarCodeWidget as I can do with QrImage?