# How to generate QR Code on PDF file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, qr-code, barcode

I have used this solution [How Can I generate QR code and Show it on a PDF page in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920331/how-can-I-generate-qr-code-and-show-it-on-a-pdf-page-in-flutter/65519333#65519333) but still QR Code isn't being printed.

My code:

```
  pdf.BarcodeWidget(
              color: PdfColor.fromHex("#000000"),
              barcode:pdf.Barcode.qrCode(), data: "My name is Bilal"
          ),
```

This is my function:

```
Future<Uint8List> func_generate_sale_pdf(PdfPageFormat format) {
    final doc = pdf.Document();

    doc.addPage(pdf.Page(build: (pdf.Context context) {
      return pdf.Center(
        child: pdf.Column(children: <pdf.Widget>[

          pdf.Text(config.app_name.toUpperCase(),
              style:
                  pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: pdf.FontWeight.bold)),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 25),
          pdf.Text(
              " ${languages.skeleton_language_objects[config.app_language]['for_enquiries_call']} : ${config.app_contacts}",
              style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 5),
          pdf.Text("${config.app_po_box}", style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 5),
          pdf.Text(
              "${languages.skeleton_language_objects[config.app_language]['receipt']} # ${receipt_data['receipt_no']}",
              style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 5),
          pdf.Text("${receipt_data['date_time']}",
              style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 30),
          pdf.Container(
            alignment: pdf.Alignment.topLeft,
            child: pdf.Text("${receipt_data['items_list'].toString()}",
                style: pdf.TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22, fontWeight: pdf.FontWeight.normal),
                textAlign: pdf.TextAlign.left),
          ),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 30),
          pdf.Container(
              child: pdf.Row(children: <pdf.Widget>[
            pdf.Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: pdf.Text(
                  languages.skeleton_language_objects[config.app_language]
                      ['total_amount'],
                  style: pdf.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20, fontWeight: pdf.FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: pdf.TextAlign.left),
            ),
            pdf.Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: pdf.Text("${receipt_data['total_amount']}",
                  style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  textAlign: pdf.TextAlign.right),
            ),
          ])),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 10),
          pdf.Container(
              child: pdf.Row(children: <pdf.Widget>[
            pdf.Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: pdf.Text(
                  languages.skeleton_language_objects[config.app_language]
                      ['total_items'],
                  style: pdf.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20, fontWeight: pdf.FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: pdf.TextAlign.left),
            ),
            pdf.Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: pdf.Text("${receipt_data['total_items']}",
                  style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  textAlign: pdf.TextAlign.right),
            ),
          ])),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 10),
          pdf.Container(
              height: 35,
              child: pdf.Row(children: <pdf.Widget>[
                pdf.Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: pdf.Text(
                      languages.skeleton_language_objects[config.app_language]
                          ['total_tax'],
                      style: pdf.TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20, fontWeight: pdf.FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: pdf.TextAlign.left),
                ),
                pdf.Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: pdf.Text("${receipt_data['total_tax_amount']}",
                      style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      textAlign: pdf.TextAlign.right),
                ),
              ])),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 35),
          pdf.Text(
              languages.skeleton_language_objects[config.app_language]
                  ['thant_you_and_come_again'],
              style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),


         //From here on, the compiler doesn't print anything.
          pdf.BarcodeWidget(
              color: PdfColor.fromHex("#000000"),
              barcode:pdf.Barcode.qrCode(), data: "My name is Bilal"
          ),
          pdf.Text("SkillzUPP Technologies: +923058431046",
              style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              textAlign: pdf.TextAlign.center),
          pdf.SizedBox(height: 10),

        ]),
      ); // Center
    }));

    return doc.save();
  }
```

Everything prints fine except QR Code and at that specific line this error is shown at terminal:

```
Helvetica-Bold has no Unicode support see https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/wiki/Fonts-Management
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem showing that line `"has no Unicode support..."` to fix that i created a folder fonts on my project and added some true type fonts to it, then i created a pdf theme for the document like below:

```
var myTheme = ThemeData.withFont(
      base: Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf")),
      bold: Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf")),
      italic: Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf")),
      boldItalic:
          Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf")),
    );
```

then i used the theme in the page of the document and the error was gone, like below:

```
Page(theme: myTheme,...)
```

I'm not sure if is the same case, but i think you should try.

Comment: Need elaboration. I have edited my question.

Comment: I edited my answer, i think could help ,i hope.

Comment: I am getting this error : ```The method 'withFont' isn't defined for the type 'Theme'.```. And compiler isn't suggesting any library to import. Moreover Font is also not recognized ```Undefined name 'Font'```. May be that's because Flutter 2.0.4 has some different way to perform it...

Comment: They are from this package, same pdf package, just different file, import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';

Comment: At last I made it. Thanks for your help. At a point after all was set, I wasn't getting the QR code displayed in pdf. Then I gave ```height: 70 ,width :70``` in Constructor of BarcodeWidget. And it worked.